# sales visualisation over time in power bi

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

in my power bi model I have sales table called invoice with the columns as follows (invoice code, partner code, date ...) another called invoiceline which specifies all sales of sinvoice with the columns as follows (invoice code, product code, quatity, unit price ...) as well as product table and partner table and a date table that I generated in power bi and which covers all the sales dates in sinvoice. after having linked the tables together and having calculated the total sales to be able to view it over time, I find that an empty value is added to my sales dates in my dashboard even if I have no sale without date and that my date table is well configured is there any solution for my problem

Comment: I have no clue about what your model looks like, but that usually happens when you have are missing a value that exists in another table. a quick check can be to create a matrix with the date and the keys of other tables ie: | Date | InvoiceNum | this should allow you to check which invoices are linked to the blank date, and then debug further

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto thank you for your answer,                                                              where should I create this matrix

Comment: is a simple visual... there is the table... and also the matrix. just create it after loading the data

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto thank you it's settled